# Prevent UIWebView from scrolling when datepicker comes into view

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiscrollview, datepicker, mobile-safari

I have a form and an input field of type date `<input type='date'>` . When the field is tapped the datepicker comes into view but the web view scrolls up automatically as the picker becomes visible.

I have tried disabling scrolling and bouncing on the web view but that didn't work i.e. `webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO; 
webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
UIView * v = [[webView subviews] lastObject];
if([v isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class] ]) {
    if ([v respondsToSelector:@selector(setScrollEnabled]) {
        [v setScrollEnabled:NO];
    }
    if ([v respondsToSelector:@selector(bounces)]) {
        [v setBounces:NO];
    }
}
```

Here you just check if the view responds to those methods and, if yes, call them.

Comment: I don't see how this is any different from what I've already said I tried but I gave it a go. As expected, the results were the same. The view still pushes up when the datepicker appears.